# Is there a way to know whether here is a 'back-to-app' bar in current app?

Tags: ios, ios9

Or how to know current app is opened by another app? Thanks...

[See picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7DGP.jpg)

Comment: I don't check it in real. But I think in order for other app to open your app, you need to register url scheme first. And when the app opens your app, your app's openURL:sourceApplication:annotation method will be invoked. I think from here you can know it. Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html

Comment: @zp_x  You are right.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, no there's no way to check.

As for @zp_x's comment, I can verify that the `openURL:sourceApplication:annotation` method is *not* invoked for Back-To-App. It *is* invoked in cases where your app's custom URL scheme is called specifically, but tapping the *Back-To-App* button to go back to your app does not appear to invoke anything other than `applicationDidBecomeActive`.

Source: Trying to implement SquareSDK in an iOS 9 app. When the Square App calls my custom URL scheme, `openURL:sourceApplication:annotation` is indeed invoked. However, if the Back-to-App button is tapped from the Square App, no such invocation occurs. This leads to some annoying bugs in my case.